# xml encryption - is ReferenceList needed?

Tags: xml, security

I have a reasonably large xml batch file (> 100K records) with the following structure:

```
<batchFile>
   <header>
      <EncryptedKey>..</EncryptedKey>
   </header>
   <data>
     <record><someData></someData><someEncryptedData></someEncryptedData></record>
     <record><someData></someData><someEncryptedData></someEncryptedData></record>
     <record><someData></someData><someEncryptedData></someEncryptedData></record>
     <record><someData></someData><someEncryptedData></someEncryptedData></record>
   </data>
</batchFile>
```

I will be using xml encryption [(link)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/) to encrypt the data.

The encryption key is the same for all the encrypted data, so I am thinking the EncryptedKey element should go in the header and the encrypted data have a keyReference to the EncryptedKey.

1) Do I need to have a referenceList from the EncryptedKey back to each encrypted data item?  This list could contain 100K references, so I'd rather not have the list if it is not required.

Comment: why are you storing the key next to the cipher text?  There is no separation of trust,  an attacker who can read this document can simply decrypt the values.

Comment: In this case, the EncryptedKey will be a session key that is encrypted with the recipients public key.

Comment: I would hire a cryptographer to review this.  This sounds way over engineered and likely very insecure.